# React Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactAutoBindMap' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to display some data in html table with reactjs. But I kept getting 
error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactAutoBindMap' of undefined. I couldn't figure out what's wrong with my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>React Flux</title>
        <script src="https://fb.me/react-0.13.3.js"></script>
        <script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="component" style="color:red"></div>

        <script type="text/jsx">


//
// create component
//
var Table = React.createClass({

    render: function render() {
        var _self = this;

        var thead = React.DOM.thead({},
            React.DOM.tr({},
                this.props.cols.map(function (col) {
                    return React.DOM.th({}, col);
            })));

        var tbody = this.props.rows.map(function (row) {
            return React.DOM.tr({},
            _self.props.cols.map(function (col) {
                return React.DOM.td({}, row[col] || "");
            }));
        });

        return React.DOM.table({}, [thead, tbody]);
    }

});

var container = document.querySelector("#container");

var tableModel = {
    cols: ["Name", "Age"],
    rows: [{
        "Name": "Chase",
            "Age": "27"
    }],

}

React.render(Table(tableModel), container);



        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the main issue you have is that your `Table` component is defined within the global scope of your page, which means that your `this` will be undefined because we're in "strict" mode.  Secondly, you are calling the `Table` component directly as a function, as opposed to using JSX.  When rendering, React is assuming a specific value for `this`, but in this case it's `undefined`, hence the error you are seeing.

So, the first step here would be to change your render function to something like this:

```
React.render(<Table cols={tableModel.cols} rows={tableModel.rows} />, container);
```

Finally, I think you'll discover after trying the above that you're targeted container is not quite right.  It's looking for an element with an id of `container` but that element doesn't existing within your html so you'll need to make a change there as well.